# How does the getPerspectiveTransform() function in the openCV library find the transformation matrix?

Tags: python, opencv, perspective

I am working on a problem in order to warp the perspective of images to get a front-parallel view. I am using the cv2.getPerspectiveTransform() function.
I give 2 sets of points:

PT1:  A set of 4 non-collinear points in the original image.

PT2:  A set of 4 points to which we want PT1 to get mapped to.

I give PT1 and PT2 as the input in cv2.getPerspectiveTransform() function to get the transformation matrix.
I give this matrix as a parameter in cv2.warpPerspective() to get the warped image.

How does the function, cv2.getPerspectiveTransform() find a transformation matrix from 2 sets of points? How is the 3×3 transformation matrix calculated from the 4 start and end points? What is the mathematical formulation?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It is done by solving simultaneous equations using the perspective transformation equation, which is a fractional (rational) linear polynomial equation. See http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/bilinearwarp/FourCornerImageWarp2.pdf

Comment: @fmw42 So, in Perspective Transform, all lines parallel to the edges in the initial image, remain straight and parallel to the edges. On top of that, the diagonals also, remain straight. Do they meet at the center as well?(from the example image in the documentation it seemed to meet at center, asking just to confirm). Also, how are the parameters of the fractional linear equation( A1,A2...) found?

Comment: I was able to open the document in the link http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/bilinearwarp/FourCornerImageWarp2.pdf
yesterday. However, unfortunately, I am not able to access it today.

Comment: Your link works fine for me. All straight lines remain straight. But the diagonals do not necessarily meet in the center.